# Как правильно развернуть RestFul написанный на Java?

Tags: java, rest

Начал заниматься изучением вопроса разработки RestFul службы. 
Разработал службу на Java в NetBeans, в качестве БД PostgreSQL, сервер приложений GlassFish 5 web. На локальной машине все хорошо работает. 
Тут встал вопрос как разместить для общего доступа?

Пробовал Azure(тут получилось только сделать PostgreSQL), MirHosting(тут окружение поднялось в два клика, но задеплойть мой war так и не получилось).
Еще есть мысли попробовать в Docker, или просто на VPS поднять все с нуля.
Может кто-то может написать по шагам как правильно развернуть службу, +/- того или иного способа?

Как я себе это представляю(инструкцию). Может кто-то посоветует другой сервер приложений т.к. GlassFish не особо популярный, но у него web-интерфейс в котором просто выбрал war и он задеплоился? (Если вы используете другой сервер приложений то если не сложно опишите подробно деплой war файла на нем)

1. У вас есть war-файл(не имеет значение из какой IDE)
2. Делаем следующее ...

Comment: А у меня примерно такой же вопрос: как залить на бесплатный хостинг свой проект на спринг буте. Может кто-то расскажет

Answer (score 1):

Приведу пример развертывания `Tomcat 8` на Ubuntu 16.04. + сервер MySql. Работа проводится через `SSH` - программа `Putty`, можно любую другую.

Значит арендуем сервер. Систему накатываем Ubuntu 16.04 чистую, без Apache и прочей фигни.

1. Устанавливаем сам Tomcat - `sudo apt-get install tomcat8`. При желании можно установить примеры - `tomcat8-docs tomcat8-admin tomcat8-examples`.
2. В Tomcat так же есть панелька в которой можно загружать `war`. как её настроить Вы можете прочесть в источнике данного примера.
3. [При надобности настраиваем Tomcat на 80 порт](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26206463/4444092)

Загрузка `war`. Корень, куда загружать файлы находится по пути `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT`. Вы можете загрузить `war` в `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/` и при старте сервер сам его распакует, а можете сделать распаковать полученный при сборке `war` и все файлы напрямую залить в `ROOT`.

Все. Вы можете зайти на сервер по адресу Вашему.

Установка MySql:
 1. Выполняем команды поочередно: 
    - `sudo apt-get update`
    - `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`
    - `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

При установке Вам будет предложено установить пароль для `root` пользователя. Будет вопрос про усложненный пароль и т.д. Надеюсь проблем с англ не будет.

Все.

[Источник установки Tomcat](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/install-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04-server.html)

[Источник установки MySql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать все предложенные варианты. И писать результаты.

Comment: И так начал ставить. Первое замечание: чтобы включить GUI в tomcat необходимо написать в **tomcat-users.xml** следующее: ' <role rolename="tomcat"/>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat, manager-gui"/>' а в ссылке @Tsyklop'a по установке tomcat, роль "tomcat" - отсутствовала. И в принципе почитал, что в 8 версии роль manager разбита на 4 разные роли. Движемся далее.

Comment: спасибо за инструкцию. Дошел до установки БД, полет нормальный, развернул свой тестовый war без БД, все ок. Базу данных буду ставить свою postgreSQL, поэтому протестировать mySQL не смогу.

Comment: @EvgenyVartavanyan ну с Postgre уже сами) я не использую его.